# How does the radius of a 30-60-90 triangle correspond to the radius of the unit circle?

Tags: trigonometry

This may have an obvious answer but my brain is riddled with this. Maybe some of my assumptions below are wrong...

If cosine and sine is the x and y coordinate on a circle with radius one, why is the 30-60-90 triangle defined as having a radius of 2? Wouldn't the cosine and sine values derived from it represent the coordinates on a circle with radius two?
Thanks.

Edit: Is this why you divide by the hypotenuse? That would scale it down by a radius of one.

Edit 2: The radius of the triangle is the hypotenuse.

Comment: You have answered your own question in your edit.

Comment: what do you call the radius of a triangle?

Comment: The radius would be the hypotenuse

Answer (score 1):

One of the features of a triangle is the circle that inscribes it. [for instance this triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoG25.png).

If by radius of a triangle you mean the radius of the circle that inscribes it, it is clear that its center is not on any edges and therefore the trigonometry functions you mention have no direct correlation. If you wanted to calculate that radius you could do it in some simple steps.

When referring to the unit circle both cosine and sine are marked assuming a rectangle. That is: cosine is defined as the x coordinate and sine as the y coordinate. That is logical as $sin=\frac{opposite}{hypotenuse}$ and $cos=\frac{adjacent}{hypotenuse}$ and in the unit circle the hypotenuse is by definition 1 unit [unit circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Pbkm.png)